# How do I figure out how my certbot is configured?

Tags: 16.04, server, nginx, certificates

I need to change the domain on my server, which I've been using certbot to get certificates for successfully. I need to switch it to a different domain though. I did not set it up initially so I have no idea how it was done, and can't figure out how to look at the current configuration.

Every answer I've found says I need to refer to the 'webroot' directory, but I'm not sure which that is exactly. It also says `the requested nginx plugin does not appear to be installed` so I don't think I'm doing it right if that's not how it was done initially.

Ubuntu 16.4 + nginx

edit: here is my config file (replaced domain and account)

```
\# renew_before_expiry = 30 days
version = 0.12.0
archive_dir = /etc/letsencrypt/archive/domain.com
cert = /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain.com/cert.pem
privkey = /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain.com/privkey.pem
chain = /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain.com/chain.pem
fullchain = /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain.com/fullchain.pem

\# Options used in the renewal process
[renewalparams]
authenticator = standalone
installer = None
account = d78fibhjdsfbgqa8734gfu9ig93
```

Comment: what does `/etc/letsencrypt/renewal/domainname.conf` say? This contains the current configuration.

Comment: Yeah I found that file but it seems to only list the cert locations, put it in the main post

Answer (score 0):

```
authenticator = standalone
```

This line basically means that certbot starts a standalone webserver. To do this, you first have to shut down your normal web server, then run certbot, and afterwards start your webserver again.

This can be done with

```
certbot -q renew --standalone --prehook "/usr/sbin/service nginx stop" --posthook "/usr/sbin/service nginx start"
```

which will stop nginx, get the certificate, and then restart nginx.

The other alternative is to install `python-certbot-nginx`, and let certbot figure out webroot automatically. This is the reference to the missing plugin (`the requested nginx plugin does not appear to be installed`).

Answer (score 0):

You need to install certbot nginx plugin.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:certbot/certbot
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install certbot python-certbot-nginx
```

Comment: How was it setup before without that plugin though?

Comment: I ran it but now it's got the wrong webroot and is displaying the nginx welcome page instead of my site